# Are repositories added to my project's POM used to locate dependencies of dependencies?

Tags: maven

Let's say I have a maven project, `A`, which depends on `B`, which in turn depends on `C`.

If I add a repository, `R`, to `A`'s `pom.xml`, will Maven look for `C` in `R`, despite `R` *not* being listed in `B`'s `pom.xml`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as long as `R` knows where to download `B` and `C`.